# How to select image for NSStatusItem for regular and retina display?

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, retina

Should I be "detecting" if it's retina display (not sure how would this work with mixed displays) and select the correct image for the NSStatusItem of my app? Please, give an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- No coding required
- You don't have to check for the display resolution
- use the [@2x Naming Convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW28) for your images and you're all set

**Example:**

You have "status.png" and "status@2x.png", as well as "status_negative.png" and "status_negative@2x.png" for the alternate image (on selection). Here is how you load it:

```c
statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
NSImage *statusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"status"];
[statusItem setImage:statusImage];
NSImage *altStatusImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"status_negative"];
[statusItem setAlternateImage:altStatusImage];

[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an example to the answer (I hope you don't mind).